# If Statements inside of OpenGL

Tags: qt, opengl

I am creating an OpenGL project that draws a square when an OpenGL view is clicked.

Here is my logic for creating the square upon a mouse click:

```
 if (mouseXPosition != 0 && mouseYPosition != 0 ){
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(mouseXPosition, (mouseYPosition + 30));
    glVertex2f((mouseXPosition + 30), mouseYPosition);
    glVertex2f(mouseXPosition, (mouseYPosition - 30));
    glVertex2f((mouseXPosition) -30, mouseYPosition);
glEnd();
 }
```

I don't think the rest of my code is needed here, but I will add it if it is. mouseXPosition and mouseYPostion are just floats that contain the position inside the OpenGL view. They are changed whenever the view is clicked to display the new position. I know that the positions are right because I print them out whenever the view is clicked.

When I run my code, there are no compilation errors, but the square isn't drawn when the mouse is clicked. Is there something that prohibits if statements within the drawing of OpenGL? If not, could someone explain to me what it is that I am doing incorrectly.

Addition Info:

The windowing system that I am using for this project is Qt, I don't think this affects the outcome of this project. For those Qt Gurus: I do call updateGL() when I set the variables so the variables inside of OpenGL should be recent.

Comment: *"Is there something that prohibits if statements within the drawing of OpenGL?"* - Even if there was (which isn't the case), I don't see any *"if statements"* inside the *"drawing of OpenGL"*, by which you can surely only mean the code inside the `glBegin/glEnd` (as otherwise any code in any program linking to OpenGL could be classified as *"within the drawing of OpenGL"*). So the question title is mere rubbish (and the question body cannot be answered without more code).

Comment: By the way, don't call `updateGL`, just call `update` like you do with any other kind of widget.

Answer (score 3):

You can only make the opengl calls inside the opengl context in the update() function - in the mouse handler you need to set some sort of flag and then put this if statement in the update()

Answer (score 1):

```
bool isClicked = false;

update()
{
    if (mouse_was_clicked)
      isClicked = true;
    if (mouse_was_released)
      isClicked = false;
}

render() {
    ...
    if (isClicked == true) {
         // your code for drawing rectangle...
    }
    ...
}
```

for detecting if mouse was clicked or released use your Gui library, some function callback or message handler.